# Ranking/Counting Rows based on Column Value

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I have some data in a format described in this sqlfilddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9cdf/2

Basically, a table with a user ID and a time that an event occured. What I'd like to do is count the events based on the time they happened by user. So, a table that looks like:

```
UID    Timestamp
-----------------
01     01-APR-12
01     01-APR-12     
02     02-APR-12     
03     05-APR-12     
01     10-APR-12     
02     11-APR-12     
03     15-APR-12     
01     20-APR-12
```

I want this to assign a numerical rank to the events based on the order in which they occurred. So, this means the table above would become:

```
UID    Timestamp     Rank
--------------------------
01     01-APR-12     1
02     02-APR-12     1
03     05-APR-12     1
01     10-APR-12     2
02     11-APR-12     2
03     15-APR-12     2
01     20-APR-12     3
```

Is there a way to do this in Oracle SQL? Or do I have to spit it out to a scripting language and take it from there?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a cursor for this

Comment: That's what I was thinking to. I've never written a cursor loop, and had trouble finding documentation on how to do so with this type of goal in mind. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the analytic function `rank`

```
SELECT uid, timestamp, rank() over (partition by uid order by timestamp) rnk
  FROM your_table
```

If there can be ties (two rows with the same `UID` and `Timestamp`) then, depending on how you want to handle ties, you may want the `dense_rank` or `row_number` analytic function instead.

Comment: Holy moly this is perfect. Thanks for the help. I knew there was an analytic function in there somewhere to do exactly what I wanted but coming from the world of MySQL/MSSQL I'm not used to having the answers I need built in.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone else comes across this, RANK, DENSE_RANK, ROW_NUMBER are also available in MSSQL.

Comment: That isn't related to the question at all, which is about Oracle.